# Change display Values of Table Cells when they equal "0"

Tags: php, foreach, while-loop

I have a table of prices.
I am running a simple while function to display the table of prices in HTML
I want to change all prices that are 0 into 'call' when displayed in html, without changing the actual mysql table.

can i do this with a foreach function within the loop somehow?

```
while ($result1 = mysql_fetch_array($query1)) {
    foreach ($result1[] as $key => $value) {
        if ($key == '0') {$value='Call';}// ???? 
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $result1['type'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $result1['25'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $result1['50'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $result1['100'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $result1['250'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $result1['500']; 
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $result1['plus'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }
```

Comment: The line `if ($key` is incomplete. Can you updated it to include your actual PHP code?

Comment: this is the part i am unsure of how to do. Thank you for the quick respones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while ($result1 = mysql_fetch_array($query1)) {
    foreach ($result1 as &$value) {
        if($value == 0) $value = 'call';
    }
    ...
```

(same as)

```
while ($result1 = mysql_fetch_array($query1)) {
    foreach ($result1 as $key => $value) {
        if($value == 0) $value[$key] = 'call';
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Peter, this works! almost..;-) can you tell me why &$value, I don't understand this markup &before$value??  ---- UPDATe: i quoted the '0'

Comment: It's reference. More info here http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php See my edited answer.